# Verify the passphrase for RSA private key

Tags: python, rsa, brute-force, passphrase

How can I verify the passphrase for RSA private key (PEM format) in python?
I want to brute force and use my own dictionary.

I created the key by this command in MacOS:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Private RSA Key detail:

Strength: 2048 bits

Algorithm:    RSA

Size:    2048

Fingerprints

SHA1:    80 09 90 30 96 8E 24 FC A9 4B 46 E1 BE B7 23 2D EC 16 2C EB

SHA256:    67 93 E2 0A 9F E7 C9 7E A9 66 AD 05 52 FD 19 8B 3E CB 8A 59 9F 51 F0 A6 65 6F 6F 9A 9D 7B 35 B9

The passphrase is : 'testing'

as @Hannu advised I ran this code but it reject the both right and wrong passphrases

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
kf = open("testing", "r")
kt = kf.read()
kf.close()
dlist = ["foo", "bar", "testing"]
for d in dlist:
    try:
        nk = RSA.importKey(kt, passphrase=d)
        print "success", d
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "nosuccess", d
        pass
```

Comment: Which encryption algorithm has been used to create your private key? You can see it in the pem file.

Comment: @Hannu are you looking for these data ==> Algorithm:RSA  and Size:2048 or something else ?

Comment: Could you maybe post the first rows of your private key file?   I tried generating a pem key with ssh-keygen and then opening it with pyCrypto, but it fails as the key is AES encrypted instead of DES, and pyCrypto seems to fail for some reason.

Comment: ... or rather modify your original post with the key info.

Comment: @Hannu I did it. Is it the thing which you looked for?

Comment: Probablty it is. I don't seem to be able to create such a key, though. Which program did you use to create the key?  My PEM formatted key files are completely different

Comment: You can try pyCrypto on your key and see if it works. I tried that but as my keys look different, the code I have is probably useless.

Comment: @Hannu I simply used this command ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com" Based on the link : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html

Comment: I used this code ==> 

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

f = open('testing','r')

RSA.importKey(f.read(), passphrase='testing')

But I get this error : Unsupported PEM encryption algorithem

The key name is testing and the passphrase is also testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to to this with Paramiko instead of pycrypto:

```
import paramiko
from paramiko import rsakey

kf = open("sshk", "r")

dlist = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "klunssi", "xyzzy"]

for d in dlist:
    kf.seek(0)
    try:
        nk = rsakey.RSAKey.from_private_key(kf, password=d)
        print "success", d
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException:
        print "fail", d
```

This works at least for me. Hope this helps.

Hannu

Comment: I ran the code, It does not accept the right pass-phrase ! It reject all pass-phrases (the right and wrong one)

Comment: Ok, then  this does not work on ssh-keygen generated keys. Let me think about it. I will update if I can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, Creating random strings is an easy job, I just want to find a method (in Python or even mac or linux command line or Java or C or C++) to feed it as passphrase into the key (in a automated way)

Comment: I just checked my pycrypto code.  It does not accept AES-128-CBC as the key encryption method. Only DES.  Curiously I found by googling a version that does accept it, but it seems to be old and not incorporated into the current crypto package.  Probably need to look elsewhere from pycrypto.

Comment: Updated my answer. Paramiko seems to be able to handle those files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the RSA Module in Crypto

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html

Something along the lines of the following would be a good starting point

```
>>> from Crypto.PrivateKey import RSA
>>>
>>> key = RSA.generate(2048)
>>> f = open('mykey.pem','w')
>>> f.write(RSA.exportKey('PEM'))
>>> f.close()
...
>>> f = open('mykey.pem','r')
>>> key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
```